# Spark doesn't seem to be fault tolerant to workers dying

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I've got a test Spark cluster going on AWS (1 master + 5 worker machines, all running Spark 2.1.0 with Scala 2.11.8 on m4.2xlarge instances), and I'm running the [ALS demo code](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html#examples) in a Spark shell to test out performance.

I noticed when I terminate all worker machines (all the while keeping the master up), the workload redistributes to the remaining workers, but when I kill all the workers, the job usually dies completely instead of patiently waiting for more workers to come along.  Is this normal behavior?

My shell session is below.  The first few lines are the ALS app, and the rest are the error messages.  You'll notice that the first time I kill all workers (executor IDs: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) the shell waits for more workers to come online, like it's supposed to.  Once I do bring up more workers (IDs: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), the application continues on its way.  But when I terminate those new workers as well, the entire job aborts with `SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure`.

Is this normal behavior?  If not, what am I doing wrong?  If so, how can I improve Spark's tolerance to (possibly all) workers dying?  Any insight into this would be appreciated.

```
Spark context Web UI available at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.133:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = spark://xxx.xxx.xxx.133:7077, app id = app-20170222012148-0005).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation._

val data = sc.textFile("s3n://my.bucket/training-set.tsv")
val ratings = data.map(_.split('\t') match { case Array(user, item, rate) =>
  Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
})

val rank = 10
val numIterations = 10
val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

[Stage 0:===========>                                             (5 + 19) / 24]
17/02/22 01:23:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on xxx.xxx.xxx.174: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 16, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /xxx.xxx.xxx.118:60180
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:221)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:899)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:275)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:119)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/02/22 01:23:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on xxx.xxx.xxx.118: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 26, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on xxx.xxx.xxx.253: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 23.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 23, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 25, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 30, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 33, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 4 on xxx.xxx.xxx.200: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 19.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 32, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 29, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 20.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 20, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 21.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 28, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 15, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 24, xxx.xxx.xxx.200, executor 4): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 3 on xxx.xxx.xxx.136: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 35, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 17.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 17, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 31, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 34, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 27, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:23:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12, xxx.xxx.xxx.136, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 0:==============================>                         (13 + 11) / 24]
17/02/22 01:26:29 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 13 on xxx.xxx.xxx.136: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 14 on xxx.xxx.xxx.200: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 11 on xxx.xxx.xxx.118: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 20.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 50, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 11): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 49, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 11): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 45, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 11): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 48, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 11): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 51, xxx.xxx.xxx.118, executor 11): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
[Stage 0:==============================>                          (13 + 8) / 24]
17/02/22 01:26:30 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 10 on xxx.xxx.xxx.174: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 41, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 14.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 38, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 16.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 40, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 16 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 43, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 37, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 9.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 60, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 12.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 36, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 39, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 12 on xxx.xxx.xxx.253: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 62, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 56, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 20.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 64, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 8.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 58, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 10.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 61, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 63, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 54, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
17/02/22 01:26:30 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 57, xxx.xxx.xxx.253, executor 12): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 12 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 16 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 16.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 40, xxx.xxx.xxx.174, executor 10): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 10 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:694)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS.run(ALS.scala:253)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:340)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS$.train(ALS.scala:357)
  ... 53 elided

scala>
```